# Макрос. Свод с разным количеством строк на листе

Tags: excel, макрос

Помогите с макросом. Нужно сделать свод из книг эксель с разным количеством строк на листе. Здесь макрос для выбора одной строки (итоговой) а надо чтоб собирал всех но только нужных. Например, Список с фио сотрудников заполнен в 10 строк а ниже на этом же листе написано просто "фио сотрудника". Помогите!!!

```
Sub LLL()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim Im_Main, Put_File, Put_File_SVOD, NAME_SVOD, schet, str_pch As Variant

Im_Main = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Put_File = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\БАЗА ДЛЯ СВОДА\"
Put_File_SVOD = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\"


Dim FS, KATALOG, FILE, MASSIV As Object
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set KATALOG = FS.GetFolder(Put_File)
    Set MASSIV = KATALOG.Files

    schet = 0
    For Each FILE In MASSIV
        schet = schet + 1
    Next

Sheets("Свод").Select
    Rows("2:65000").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

NAME_SVOD = Trim(Range("G1").Value)

str_pch = 7
If schet <> 0 Then
   For Each FILE In MASSIV
       Workbooks.Open Filename:=Trim(FILE)

       Rows("19:19").Select
       Selection.Copy

       Windows(Im_Main).Activate
       Rows(Trim(Str(str_pch)) + ":" + Trim(Str(str_pch))).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Windows(Dir(Trim(FILE))).Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close

    str_pch = str_pch + 1
   Next
End If

    Sheets("Свод").Copy

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        Put_File_SVOD + NAME_SVOD + ".XLS", FileFormat _
        :=xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:= _
        False, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close


 MsgBox "ГОТОВО"







Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно найти последнюю заполненную строку:

```
Dim iRow as Long // добавлено
iRow = cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row // добавлено
If schet <> 0 Then
   For Each FILE In MASSIV
       Workbooks.Open Filename:=Trim(FILE)

       Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(iRow, 2)).Select // скопировать от строки 1 столбца 1 до последней заполненной строки столбца 2
       Selection.Copy

       Windows(Im_Main).Activate
       Rows(Trim(Str(str_pch)) + ":" + Trim(Str(str_pch))).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Windows(Dir(Trim(FILE))).Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close

    str_pch = str_pch + 1
   Next
End If
```